# Read last line of STDOUT

Tags: c#, .net, stdout

I am executing a program through `Process.Start()`. I tried redirecting the output to get the lines.

For now, however, I only need the last line.

Is there a way to read the last line only or do I still need to the whole `redirectStandaroutput = false;` etc?

Is there a simpler way?

If I have to go by the `process.Redirect()`, I tried following the examples on MSDN and other sources with `outputdatareceived` event, but my output only gets written to the console at the end and is not async.

Comment: No, there's not a simpler way. You need to read the entire output and simply discard everything other than the last line.

Comment: Thanks Servy. I will read the complete op.

Comment: Or you can read line by line using StreamReader.ReadLine() -> http://www.gamedev.net/topic/521470-c-launching-another-process-and-capturing-stdout/

Answer (score 1):

Once you use `process.Start()` the only way to read output that I know is to use `.RedirectStandardInput = true;`.
And as Standart output is a stream object, last line could be read only by reading whole stream.

BTW `proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd()` will hang your thread untill process will exit, and if you'll get any promts during reading - your app will hang up.